# React Typescript: Optional Functions are not considered undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am building a React Functional Component and my component should offer an optional function prop.
If this prop/the function is provided, I want to render something and also enable the clicking on the component.

```
  export type AvatarProps = {
  onEdit?: () => void;
};

const Avatar: FunctionComponent<AvatarProps> = (props: AvatarProps) => {
 props.onEdit && (console.log("test");
```

Unfortunately the function is always considered and is never undefined, although I do not provide it.

In the Google Chrome React Add-on it notices the function as
onEdit:ƒ actionHandler() {} if no function is provided.
If I provide the function, the Add-on notices
onEdit
:
ƒ onEdit() {}

How can I properly check if the function was provided or not.

EDIT:
I am currently testing in Storybook:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Story } from '@storybook/react';
import Avatar, { AvatarProps } from './Avatar';

export default {
  title: 'Avatar',
  component: Avatar,
};

const Template: Story<AvatarProps> = args => <Avatar {...args} />;

export const Editable = Template.bind({});
Editable.args = {
  onEdit: () => {
    console.log('test');
  },
};

export const NotEditable = Template.bind({});
NotEditable.args = {
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're actually using `<Avatar />`?

Comment: @jnpdx I added it in the question

Comment: My issue is, that even the NotEditable test is creating the "test" output in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Under your Storybook parameters, you can set `argTypesRegex: null` to prevent this default behavior.

```
export default {
  parameters: {
    actions: {
      argTypesRegex: null,
    },
  }
}
```

- [Relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/addon-smart-knobs/issues/63)